# "Error creating window handle" after define overridden WndProc method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, winapi, wndproc

I created a simple WinForms project, didn't do absolutely anything, just added this code in Form1.cs:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
    }
```

And that's it. It compiles, but throw an exception "Error creating window handle". Like on the screen:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/ivgww5.jpg

Another thing is I have a project created couple of days before, that use WndProc without any exceptions. 
Can anybody explain me what could be the problem here?

Thanks for help,

btw. Stack trace:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Johny\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Temp\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Calling base.WndProc() is a rock-hard requirement.  Right now the WM_NCCREATE message isn't being processed, so no window is getting created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overriding the WndProc method and not handling every possible WM_* message, thus not properly processing them.

To fix this issue you must pass the message to base.WndProc(..)

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
   base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Override a WndProc is useful when you want to do something with some incoming WM_* message, however providing a full WndProc implementation in your own is really tricky, the simplest way is to forward the messages you are not interested on to base class.